# COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore : file does not exist

Tags: c#, docker

I'm learning about Docker and I want to use it with API.
So I create a Web API .net Core in Visual Studio. I have a Dockerfile include which looks like this :

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestAPI"
RUN dotnet build "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestAPI.dll"]
```

My API is located here :

> C:\Users\myUserName\source\repos\TestAPI\TestAPI

In this folder, I used the following commands (following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows) :

> dotnet publish -c Release

Then

> docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .

There I have the following error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.666MB
Step 1/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
 ---> 2b5756fb108e
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a929c369e15
Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 082fd5126acf
Step 4/17 : EXPOSE 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7a1754c6f4d
Step 5/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
7.0: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
5c5b06ba6593: Already exists
1472b3edb703: Already exists
889bf336c328: Already exists
e5629affa429: Already exists
b64d9c6e57ac: Already exists
96cc347bbc7d: Already exists
1b22b3d5eca3: Already exists
9d5e031ac0b3: Already exists
bd841233ce2e: Pull complete
e44054da3c64: Pull complete
45706e203860: Pull complete
5b7c3bc01247: Pull complete
8ea517ed84da: Pull complete
079a6960634d: Pull complete
554af2bee681: Pull complete
ba5738916125: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:24f22e1142432dea3a34d350686be77be5e454ccb9fab7c00d67cd03c6e000a6
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
 ---> d9ab3561c5c8
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 823883bac988
Removing intermediate container 823883bac988
 ---> 7048664fb626
Step 7/17 : COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat TestAPI\TestAPI.csproj: file does not exist
```

I already look to find a solution but I don't really understand why I have this error.

Comment: What directory is the Dockerfile in?  The `TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj` file path will be interpreted relative to the path argument to `docker build`, in your example the current directory `.`.

Comment: The dockerfile is located here : C:\Users\myUserName\source\repos\TestAPI\TestAPI\Dockerfile

Comment: If you're already starting inside the `TestAPI` directory, you don't need to include that leading path component on the left-hand side of `COPY`.

Comment: this one ? `COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"]`